# Radio button is not getting checked on page load by default in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a form which has two radio buttons say Yes and No. I need to select No on page load or by default we can say.

In my HTML-

```
<md-radio-group>
 <md-radio-input #rdoYes [value]="true">Yes</md-radio-input>
 <md-radio-input #rdoNo [value]="false"[checked]="rdoNo===false">No</md-radio-input>
</md-radio-group>
```

I am doing something like this but the "No" radio button is not getting selected by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a fixed value, then you should get ride off those `[]`, like `value="true"`.

About the selection in itself, you should probably do `[checked]="rdoNo.value === false"`.

Please let me know in comment if you get any progress and I'll be pleased to help you to end the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. If you notice some mistakes in the syntax comments I did, please let me know.

Comment: For [value]=" ' true ' " we cannot use in this case as it is a boolean.